# Node.js with in memory DB and transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, in-memory-database

Is there a way to work with Node.js with in memory DB(for example- nedb) and transactions?
I want to use in memory DB for performance and I need transaction in order to be able to do rollbacks if an operation isn't valid